# Автогенерация определенного количества полей ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Недавно начал учить питон. Встала следующая задача: необходимо на основе введенной переменной, создать несколько полей ввода (вводится количество слоев материала, а должны вывестись поля, куда можно вписать характеристики каждого слоя). Реально ли это каким-то образом сделать с помощью Tkinter? Заранее благодарен за ответ:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

some_variable = 5

root = tk.Tk()

for n in range(some_variable):
    tk.Label(root, text='Автоматически созданное поле №' + str(n)).grid(row=n, column=0)
    tk.Entry(root).grid(row=n, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```